# BackupPC incremental backup problem

Tags: incremental-backup, backuppc

I have BackupPC  application in CentOS 5.. clients are windows  and RHEL machines.. I could take the Fullbackup for the client mahines ..But I can't take the increental backup.. When I  took the incremental backup , it start incremental backup, but after completion of the task .. i see that the backup directory contain full back of all the data ... what is the reason?   pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/faq/BackupPC.html#backup_basics), it's meant to appear that way:

> BackupPC "fills-in" incremental backups when browsing or restoring, based on the levels of each backup, giving every backup a "full" appearance. This makes browsing and restoring backups much easier: you can restore from any one backup independent of whether it was an incremental or full.

An unrelated note: Please try to write correct English on web forums. It's very hard for non-native speakers who have only learned "the Queen's English" to understand what you're saying otherwise.